# (struct sockaddr *)&net - объясните что значит

Tags: c

Ребят, объясните подробно по полочкам что значит `(struct sockaddr *)&net`, не могу понять.
Сама net это структура типа struct sockaddr_in

Теперь не "дубликат"

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, нет, этот вопрос там был в качестве второстепенного и на него акцент не делался

Comment: "объясните подробно по полочкам" - чтобы было ясно, что вам объяснить, привидите в вопросе источник, в котором вы ознакомились с  struct sockaddr_in,  и поясните, что вам там осталось непонятно.

Comment: Так я и задал вопрос для того, чтобы мне объяснили то, что я не понял

Comment: Да, но вы не указали - что конкретно вы не поняли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что происходит в Вашем коде:

1. Берётся адрес переменной `net`
2. Адрес преобразуется с помощью явного приведения типов к указателю на структуру `sockaddr`

Вероятно (или, по крайней мере, так должно быть) структуры `sockaddr_in` и `sockaddr` имеют одинаковый размер, а возможно, и поля. Тогда такое преобразование просто изменит тип получаемого адреса, чтобы его, например, можно было передать в функцию, принимающую аргумент определённого типа. То есть, если функция принимает аргумент типа `sockaddr`, и мы никак не можем это изменить,  и также у нас есть переменная типа `sockaddr_in`, и при этом `sockaddr` и `sockaddr_in` являются идентичными или преобразуемыми друг в друга, мы можем использовать явное преобразование, чтобы иметь возможность передачи в функцию.

Вот пример реализации структур:

```cpp
struct sockaddr
{
    int x;
    float y;
};

struct sockaddr_in
{
    int z;
    float pp;
};
```

Названия полей взяты полностью "с потолка", это просто пример, чтобы было понятно, как разные структуры могут быть идентичны.

И теперь можно сделать такое же преобразование:

```cpp
sockaddr_in net;
sockaddr * net_p =  (struct sockaddr *)& net;
```

Тогда `net_p` будет иметь тип `sockaddr *`.

[Здесь](https://learnc.info/c/structures.html) довольно много про структуры, в том числе и про приведение типов.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас прочту)

Comment: @name Отметьте, пожалуйста, наиболее полезный из ответов, как решение.

Comment: на данный момент ни на один из своих вопросов я понятного для меня ответа не нашел, на данный момент я жду пока мне ответят на мои комментарии как на прошлом, так и на этом вопросе дабы уточнить некоторые детали, я не говорю что ответы плохие, просто я слишком туп:-)

Comment: @name Я отредактировал свой ответ. Возможно, станет понятнее.

Comment: сейчас, дайте мне переварить всю информацию)

Comment: ой, капец я тупой) Совершенно забыл что тип данных в скобках, допустим `(int) name `, это временное приведение типа))

Answer (score 0):

Есть переменная `net`.

Есть ее адрес - `&net`, указатель на тип переменной (вы не сказали, что именно собой представляет `net`.

Этот указатель можно привести к типу "Указатель на структуру `sockaddr`" - это и есть `(struct sockaddr *)&net` - указатель на структуру типа `struct sockaddr`, находящуюся в памяти там, где находится переменная `net`.

Примерно так.

Comment: а почему &net это указатель на переменную net? & же просто операция взятия адреса и никакой указатель изначально этот адрес не хранит

Comment: @name адрес `net` приводится к указателю на структуру